Add a last row variable into a range variable in Google App Script
I'm using the Google App Script
I'm trying to add the last Row(N) variable into a range variable(rngForForm) so that the range will be dynamic instead of being hardcoded. The left,sprLeft & setLeft variables are working, I just cannot get the rngForForm variable to accept the N value
so I need it to be something like this:
var rngForForm = "$B$3:$B(N variable here)";
function usingFunction2() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = 'sprintuniquename';

  var selectedSheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var mySheet = selectedSheet;
  var lastRow = mySheet.getLastRow();
  var N = lastRow;

  for (var i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
    var left = 'LEFT($A$3:$A' + N + ',3)';
    var sprLeft = 'LEFT($A$3:$A' + N + ',9)';
    var setLeft = 'LEFT($A$3:$A' + N + ',12)';
    var rngForForm = "$B$3:$B$1000";
  }

  var trimData = mySheet.getRange(rngForForm).setFormula(left);
  var sourceVals = trimData.getValues();```


You can use a template literal:
var rngForForm = `$B$3:$B$${N}`;

You could also use R1C1 notation:
var trimData = mySheet.getRange(3, 2, N-2).setFormula(left);

P.S. Your for loop is totally useless; just do this instead:
// [...]
var N = lastRow;

var left = 'LEFT($A$3:$A' + N + ',3)';
var sprLeft = 'LEFT($A$3:$A' + N + ',9)';
var setLeft = 'LEFT($A$3:$A' + N + ',12)';
var rngForForm = "$B$3:$B$1000";

var trimData = mySheet.getRange(rngForForm).setFormula(left);
// [...]

P.S. 2: I'm assuming that you later reassign different values to mySheet and N, while still needing to use the original values of selectedSheet and lastRow. Otherwise, why not just do this:
// ...
var mySheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var N = mySheet.getLastRow();
// ...


If you feel your answers are unfairly targeted, flag for moderator attention.

It's not best practice to use R1C1.

Thank you @TheMaster. I wasn't sure, but I interpreted the downvotes as being related to my proposing A1 notation before R1C1; it was the only thing I could think of. I rolled back to the previous version of the answer.

TBH, I don't know users in the apps script tag, who'd downvote for that. I think the votes are targeted for some other reason. If there's a pattern for few of your answers, it's better to flag for moderator attention for targeted voting.

You can try this alternative answer using the parameters of getting the range in Google Apps script
var rngForForm = mySheet.getRange(3, 2, mySheet.getLastRow());

REFERENCES:

getRange()
getLastRow()


I understand what you are trying to do, however, transferring the getLastRow returned value back to A1 notation is kind of redundant and there is a more finesse way of getting the specified range using Google Apps script which is using the four parameters of getRange() function, see the reference.
